# After importing eml to pst using redemption.dll Not maintaining format of Email body for eml.

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I have an issue with redemption or may be other. i have eml file which is in proper format in body. but if i import that eml to pst or msg then format of that mail is changes in output file. some new extra lines are getting added or some of font is changes and color of text is also change. it disturb total body format. please give me solution, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can oy ube a bit more specific? What is your code? Does this happen with any EML file or just some? Can you send a problematic EML to dmitry at dimastr dot com?

Comment: if you have any solution please tell me